# Azure Logic App : Gmail Connector "Reply to email (V2)" Action is Creating a different Thread

Tags: azure, gmail, azure-logic-apps

When using Azure Logic App : Gmail Connector, "When a new email arrives" Trigger, we are receiving Message ID and Thread ID

[image]
[image]

But on calling "Reply to email (V2)" Action with Message ID received, it is creating a separate thread with the existing thread data but I am not understanding why it is creating a different thread. Is there any way we can get reply in the same thread, the way it happens with Outlook Connector.

Is there any way I can use Thread Id for replying to the same thread? I am not sure what is the use of Thread ID. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end it works fine and we can able to see only one thread Id while using `Reply to email (V2)`. One of the reasons you might be receiving this is that you have applied filters on a particular type of mail and then are moved to another location/folder.

### **RESULTS:**

#### RUN-1

[image]

#### RUN-2

[image]

**NOTE:** When you are triggering this email and consider if the mail is being replied back to the same location/folder then it would create a loop and trigger many times unless you diable the logic app.

Comment: I am able to see that Thread Id is same in my case also. But when I am replying using Logic App with message Id, the receiver email is getting in separate thread with existing data. I am not understanding why it is creating new thread with existing thread Id and data instead of just showing the reply in existing thread.

Comment: @AshishP. Are there any filters applied? because I can able to view them in one thread.

Comment: No filters are applied. I tried with 2 accounts both are creating new thread with existing email data. If possible, can we connect ? If yes, please ping me on the linked in https://www.linkedin.com/in/ashish-panjwani-253180a6/

Comment: @AshishP. Can you please try the same in your consumption plan if you are not already doing?